# SwiftyDropbox getCurrentAccount Error

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I'm trying out SwiftyDropbox in an iOS project and when I use this code from the tutorial...

```
if let client = Dropbox.authorizedClient {

  // Get the current user's account info
  client.users.getCurrentAccount().response { response, error in
    print(response)

    if let account = response {
      self.accountStatus.text = "\(account.email)"
    } else {
      print(error!)
    }
  }
}
```

...and I print `response` it returns nil and I get the following error in the Xcode console:

> Bad Input: Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": request body: could not decode input as JSON

I'm using version **2.0.3** of the CocoaPod.

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I'm just thankful that you've posted an example of how to use the weird return type of `getCurrentAccount`, because the library documentation sure doesn't explain this.

Comment: Diddo.  It's vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with version 2.0.3 that we're working on.

In the meantime, you can work around this by downgrading to 2.0.2 for now.

Comment: This should be fixed now in release 3.0.0.

Comment: Nice! I haven't been able to find any release notes. Have the changes been documented anywhere yet?

Comment: Just this: https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox/releases/tag/3.0.0 There's just the one `Auth` to `OAuth` change to be aware of.